# Core Data UML Diagram mindset

Tags: ios, database, swift, core-data

So I'm building my first "real" application with Core Data and I have a question whether I am thinking the right way or not.

Here's my Core Data uml:

[image: UML Diagram - Core Data project]

I'm having some thoughts about my relationships.

1. A mother should be able to have multiple litters, but a litter can only be assigned to one mother - Have I done this right?
2. The same thing with litters and puppies.
3. A puppy should be able to have multiple weights since it should be updated. Is it correct to break it out to it's own entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that seems right, but I wouldn't recommend to make separate entity for weight - it's absolutely just an attribute of Puppy.
Moreover, Mother and Puppy entities are of the same entity (they are all dogs), so you can create base entity Dog and declare weight attribute in it and then inherite Mother and Puppy from this base entity - this is good database design.

Comment: Multiple weights are fine, probably want a date attribute on the entity though. I'd try not to use entity inheritance if you can help it